# iOS can you view SVN repository on iPhone/iPad via PuTTY Pagent?

Tags: ios, svn, putty, pageant

I currently develop on a Windows PC and store the code in an `SVN` repository that is accessed via a combination of `SVN`, `PuTTY`, and `Pageant`. I would like to be able to view code in the repository on an iPad but I am unsure if this is possible because of the PuTTY and Pageant element?

I'm just researching this at the moment and can see there is an SVN client for iOS but I'm not sure how to get the PuTTY/Pageant working with this?

No code to show

I hope it is possible to view the files as I going to remote locations and don't have the ability to carry a laptop and would like to be able to use my phone

Comment: PuTTY is just SSH client. So you need SVN client for iPad that supports SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that you need SVN client to view data in your repository? You could use a [web interface](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/svn-web-interface/) instead. For example, take a look at the [web UI built in VisualSVN Server](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#webkit/view/head/trunk). It works great with mobile web browsers, activates automatically and works out of the box (no configuration required) when you use VisualSVN Server.

Note that Apache+DAV_svn [supports (very) basic repository browsing capabilities](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/httpd/#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.browsing) and there is more functional [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/). But they both need manual installation and setup.